# Convert time to seconds in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Input:

| ID | PERSONAL_AUX | OUTBOUND_AUX |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0:09:00 | 0:00:08 |
| 1 | 0:19:00 | 0:00:40 |
| 1 | 0:13:00 | 0:00:33 |
| 1 | 0:08:00 | 0:00:22 |

Output:

| ID | PERSONAL_AUX | OUTBOUND_AUX | PERSONAL_AUX_SEC | OUTBOUND_AUX_SEC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0:09:00 | 0:00:08 | 540 | 8 |
| 1 | 0:19:00 | 0:00:40 | 1140 | 40 |

Hello all, can somebody help me convert time into seconds. I am new to pyspark.TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`unix_timestamp`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp.html) function to convert time to seconds

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = input \
  .withColumn("Personal_aux_sec", F.unix_timestamp(F.col("PERSONAL_AUX"), 'H:mm:ss')) \
  .withColumn("outbound_aux_sec", F.unix_timestamp(F.col("OUTBOUND_AUX"), 'H:mm:ss'))
```

Answer (score 1):

If your pattern remains consistent , you can parse the pattern into individual components = `HH:MM:SS`

And finally generate the required column by converting each parsed component into seconds

#### Data Preparation

```
d = {
    'ID':[1] * 4,
    'PERSONAL_AUX':['0:09:00','0:19:00','0:13:00','0:08:00'],
    'OUTBOUND_AUX':['0:00:08','0:00:40','0:00:33','0:00:22']
}

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(d))

+---+------------+------------+
| ID|PERSONAL_AUX|OUTBOUND_AUX|
+---+------------+------------+
|  1|     0:09:00|     0:00:08|
|  1|     0:19:00|     0:00:40|
|  1|     0:13:00|     0:00:33|
|  1|     0:08:00|     0:00:22|
+---+------------+------------+
```

#### Parse & Split Pattern

```
sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('PERSONAL_AUX_HOUR',F.split(F.col('PERSONAL_AUX'),':').getItem(0).cast(IntegerType()))\
                 .withColumn('PERSONAL_AUX_MIN',F.split(F.col('PERSONAL_AUX'),':').getItem(1).cast(IntegerType()))\
                 .withColumn('PERSONAL_AUX_SEC',F.split(F.col('PERSONAL_AUX'),':').getItem(2).cast(IntegerType()))\
                 .withColumn('OUTBOUND_AUX_HOUR',F.split(F.col('OUTBOUND_AUX'),':').getItem(0).cast(IntegerType()))\
                 .withColumn('OUTBOUND_AUX_MIN',F.split(F.col('OUTBOUND_AUX'),':').getItem(1).cast(IntegerType()))\
                 .withColumn('OUTBOUND_AUX_SEC',F.split(F.col('OUTBOUND_AUX'),':').getItem(2).cast(IntegerType()))
```

#### Standardisation to Seconds

```
sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('PERSONAL_AUX_SEC',F.col('PERSONAL_AUX_HOUR')*3600 + F.col('PERSONAL_AUX_MIN')*60 + F.col('PERSONAL_AUX_SEC'))\
                 .withColumn('OUTBOUND_AUX_SEC',F.col('OUTBOUND_AUX_HOUR')*3600 + F.col('OUTBOUND_AUX_MIN')*60 + F.col('OUTBOUND_AUX_SEC'))\

sparkDF = sparkDF.drop(*['PERSONAL_AUX_HOUR','PERSONAL_AUX_MIN','OUTBOUND_AUX_HOUR','OUTBOUND_AUX_MIN'])
                             
sparkDF.show()

+---+------------+------------+----------------+----------------+
| ID|PERSONAL_AUX|OUTBOUND_AUX|PERSONAL_AUX_SEC|OUTBOUND_AUX_SEC|
+---+------------+------------+----------------+----------------+
|  1|     0:09:00|     0:00:08|             540|               8|
|  1|     0:19:00|     0:00:40|            1140|              40|
|  1|     0:13:00|     0:00:33|             780|              33|
|  1|     0:08:00|     0:00:22|             480|              22|
+---+------------+------------+----------------+----------------+
```